# Don't know where to load template "spring.ftl" in Freemarker html template with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I use Freemarker templating in my Srping application to generate PDF files from HTML template.
All template was encoded in Base64 and saved in database. So to generate my PDF file I load the Base64 document and call Freemarker.
During the processing I obtain this error :

```
----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #import "/spring.ftl" as spring  [in template "my_template.pdf" at line 5, column 1]
----

Caused by: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Don't know where to load template "spring.ftl" from because the "template_loader" FreeMarker setting wasn't set (Configuration.setTemplateLoader), so it's null.
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2957) ~[freemarker-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.getTemplateForInclusion(Environment.java:3062) ~[freemarker-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.getTemplateForInclusion(Environment.java:3024) ~[freemarker-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.getTemplateForImporting(Environment.java:3186) ~[freemarker-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.importLib(Environment.java:3171) ~[freemarker-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.importLib(Environment.java:3135) ~[freemarker-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at freemarker.core.LibraryLoad.accept(LibraryLoad.java:65) ~[freemarker-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
```

You can found my Freemarker configuration :

```
package com.omb;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class FreeMarkerConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setExposeSpringMacroHelpers(true);
        viewResolver.setExposeRequestAttributes(true);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");
        Properties settings = new Properties();
        settings.setProperty("auto_import", "/spring.ftl as spring");
        configurer.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

Template html

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div><@spring.message "MESSAGE_FROM_RESSOURCE_BUNDLE"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Template generator code :

```
public static byte[] generateDoc(String templateName, String templateDocument, Map<String, Object> objects, Map<String, Object> params) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        Map<String, Object> ownParams = checkParams(params);
        Configuration config = getConfig();
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = getConverterProperties();

        Template template = new Template(templateName, new StringReader(templateDocument), config);

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

            Environment env = template.createProcessingEnvironment(objects, writer);
            populateEnvironnment(env);
            env.process();

            ByteArrayOutputStream fos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfDocument output = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(fos));
            output.setDefaultPageSize((PageSize) ownParams.get(PAGE_SIZE));

            try (ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray())) {
                HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(in, output, converterProperties);
            }
            return fos.toByteArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you generating the PDF? Please add the full stacktrace (not just the freemarker part).

Comment: I check my war and in the WEB-INF I dont have any view folder

Comment: I added the template generator code

Comment: Looks like that code isn't using anything of the configuration you have in there. The viewresolver is pretty much useless as it is for view rendering not for PDF generation.

Comment: In addition I don't think you can load from `/WEB-INF/views` if you are not rendering a view. So you would need to place the `.ftl` file in the classpath instead of in `/WEB-INF`.

Comment: In fact I dont need another ftl file else the spring.ftl. The properties auto_import shouldnt import it automaticaly or should I put it mabnualy into the webapp ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255939/discussion-between-ousmane-mbinte-and-m-deinum).

Comment: The error message states that the `template_loader` configuration setting wasn't set at all. That suggests that you aren't using the same `Configuration` that was created at the beginning of your question.